# get the expanded row id in postData jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm strugling to get the expanded row id in a jqgrid postData, I want something like:

```
postData: {
  objectID: expandedRowId
}
```

how can i get the expandedRowId to send it to server with my parameters. I've seen something like:

```
postData : {
   ...
   nodeid:rc.id,
   n_left:rc.lft,
   n_right:rc.rgt,
   n_level:rc.level,
   ...
}
```

but what is "rc"??
plzz help

Comment: there must be some reference to `rc` somewhere in your code.. check it out

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but it's unclear what you want. I have to guess what you mean. Is `expandedRowId` a variable which you defined in your code and which you change somewhere? In the case you can define `objectID` property of `postData` as function:

```js
postData: {
    objectID: function () { return expandedRowId; }
}
```

see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) for more details.